# Bison Yacc resolve shift reduce conflict

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison, yacc

How can I change this to remove the shiftt/reduce conflict?

```
var_part
    :                                           
    |   VAR var_declaration SEMIC var_part_multi
    ;

var_part_multi
    :   var_declaration SEMIC var_part_multi    
    |                                           
    ;

var_declaration
    :   ID id_list COLON ID                     
    ;

id_list
    :   COMMA ID id_list                        
    |                                           
    ;
```

I have two conflicts and the y.output gives me this:

```
State 19 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
State 59 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

state 19

    4 var_part: VAR var_declaration SEMIC . var_part_multi
    5 var_part_multi: . var_declaration SEMIC var_part_multi
    6               
    7 var_declaration: . ID id_list COLON ID

    ID  shift, and go to state 12

    ID        [reduce using rule 6 (var_part_multi)]
    $default  reduce using rule 6 (var_part_multi)

    var_part_multi   go to state 33
    var_declaration  go to state 34

state 59

    5 var_part_multi: . var_declaration SEMIC var_part_multi
    5               | var_declaration SEMIC . var_part_multi
    6               | .  [ID, BEGIN, DOT, IF, FUNCTION, REPEAT, SEMIC, VAL, WHILE, WRITELN]
    7 var_declaration: . ID id_list COLON ID

    ID  shift, and go to state 12

    ID        [reduce using rule 6 (var_part_multi)]
    $default  reduce using rule 6 (var_part_multi)

    var_part_multi   go to state 95
    var_declaration  go to state 34
```

I know the problem is with the ID, it has two possible routes but I've been trying for the last hour changing the rules, adding precedences and whatnot and wasn't able to remove the conflict. Can you guys help?

Comment: Shift/Reduce conflicts are not necessarily bad as are reduce/reduce conflicts. If is frequently better to lives with some shift/reduce conflict than to make the grammar more complex to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't pasted enough of your grammar to answer the question, but it is almost certainly related to the fact that `var_part_multi` can be empty.

The question is what is the context of the use of `var_part`; specifically, how it is possible for `var_part` to be followed by something which starts with `ID`.

In that case, since `var_part_multi` can be empty, the parser will have to choose between starting a non-empty `var_part_multi` using the `ID`, or reducing an empty `var_part_multi` (and then reducing a `var_part`), which will allow the `ID` to start the non-terminal which can follow `var_part`.

By the way, in your paste of the y.output file, the third line under `State 19` (the one which starts with the number `6`) has been truncated. It should resemble the third line under `State 59`.

If you can't figure out by examining your grammar how `ID` could follow `var_part`, it might help to trace the state machine backwards from one of the two conflicted states.

Comment: I was trying to figure it out and I thought it was that, that it could accept an empty or keep going. How to fix this for either the situations (shift and reduce)?

Comment: @andrepcg: I honestly don't know because I have no idea of the context. But presumably the problem is that the language is ambiguous, because the statement following the `var` section could be an assignment, which starts with an `ID`. If you showed more of the grammar, it might be possible to provide a better answer. By the way, there is no need to eliminate left-recursion from an LR grammar; doing so makes the grammar harder to read and more expensive to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried more than one independent yacc implementation and all of them agree that the grammar you've posted is conflict-free. For example:

```
$ cat so.y
%token VAR ID COLON SEMIC COMMA

%%

var_part
    :                                           
    |   VAR var_declaration SEMIC var_part_multi
    ;

var_part_multi
    :   var_declaration SEMIC var_part_multi    
    |                                           
    ;

var_declaration
    :   ID id_list COLON ID                     
    ;

id_list
    :   COMMA ID id_list                        
    |                                           
    ;
$ cat y.output
state 0 //

    0 $accept: . var_part
    1 var_part: .  [$end]

    $end  reduce using rule 1 (var_part)
    VAR   shift, and goto state 2

    var_part  goto state 1

state 1 // [$end]

    0 $accept: var_part .  [$end]

    $end  accept

state 2 // VAR

    2 var_part: VAR . var_declaration SEMIC var_part_multi

    ID  shift, and goto state 4

    var_declaration  goto state 3

state 3 // VAR ID COLON ID [SEMIC]

    2 var_part: VAR var_declaration . SEMIC var_part_multi

    SEMIC  shift, and goto state 11

state 4 // VAR ID

    5 var_declaration: ID . id_list COLON ID
    7 id_list: .  [COLON]

    COLON  reduce using rule 7 (id_list)
    COMMA  shift, and goto state 6

    id_list  goto state 5

state 5 // VAR ID [COLON]

    5 var_declaration: ID id_list . COLON ID

    COLON  shift, and goto state 9

state 6 // VAR ID COMMA

    6 id_list: COMMA . ID id_list

    ID  shift, and goto state 7

state 7 // VAR ID COMMA ID

    6 id_list: COMMA ID . id_list
    7 id_list: .  [COLON]

    COLON  reduce using rule 7 (id_list)
    COMMA  shift, and goto state 6

    id_list  goto state 8

state 8 // VAR ID COMMA ID [COLON]

    6 id_list: COMMA ID id_list .  [COLON]

    COLON  reduce using rule 6 (id_list)

state 9 // VAR ID COLON

    5 var_declaration: ID id_list COLON . ID

    ID  shift, and goto state 10

state 10 // VAR ID COLON ID

    5 var_declaration: ID id_list COLON ID .  [SEMIC]

    SEMIC  reduce using rule 5 (var_declaration)

state 11 // VAR ID COLON ID SEMIC

    2 var_part: VAR var_declaration SEMIC . var_part_multi
    4 var_part_multi: .  [$end]

    $end  reduce using rule 4 (var_part_multi)
    ID    shift, and goto state 4

    var_declaration  goto state 13
    var_part_multi   goto state 12

state 12 // VAR ID COLON ID SEMIC [$end]

    2 var_part: VAR var_declaration SEMIC var_part_multi .  [$end]

    $end  reduce using rule 2 (var_part)

state 13 // VAR ID COLON ID SEMIC ID COLON ID [SEMIC]

    3 var_part_multi: var_declaration . SEMIC var_part_multi

    SEMIC  shift, and goto state 14

state 14 // VAR ID COLON ID SEMIC ID COLON ID SEMIC

    3 var_part_multi: var_declaration SEMIC . var_part_multi
    4 var_part_multi: .  [$end]

    $end  reduce using rule 4 (var_part_multi)
    ID    shift, and goto state 4

    var_declaration  goto state 13
    var_part_multi   goto state 15

state 15 // VAR ID COLON ID SEMIC ID COLON ID SEMIC [$end]

    3 var_part_multi: var_declaration SEMIC var_part_multi .  [$end]

    $end  reduce using rule 3 (var_part_multi)

$
```